# Jackson PrettyPrint for Spring 4

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

The goal is to make Jackson format response from controllers with PrettyPrint.
Thats my configuration for it:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
            if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = jsonMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
                objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
                objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thats how a controller looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/facebook", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> authorizeViaFacebook(
        @RequestParam(value = "token") String token) throws DefaultException{

    Facebook facebook = this.facebookUtility.getFacebook(token);
    org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User facebookUserProfile = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile("me");

    User loggedInUser = User.signInWithFacebookProfile(facebookUserProfile);

    return ImmutableMap.of("token", loggedInUser.tokenForAuthentication(), "user", loggedInUser);
}
```

But no matter what I do it still prints it straight. I tried different configurations but still no success.

Here is a POM file for Jackson:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Spring version is 4.2.4.RELEASE.

How do I make Jackson use PrettyPrint format?

Comment: Did you make sure your browser understands application/json right?

Comment: @Stefan I use a terminal mostly. But its a good idea to check a response look in a browser.

Comment: @Stefan browser understand application/json correctly and still prints it in a single line.

Comment: Try to use objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true) instead enable

Comment: @user2669657 tried. No luck. Maybe its something with a method that I use to configure a mapper?

Comment: Are you sure the if instanceof returns true? I use it with overriding the method configureMessageConverters and works

Comment: @user2669657 it does for a jackson message converter. Tried to call configureMessageConverters method and creating a converter with an object mapper from scratch but still nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve faced a similar problem once when trying to config a Jackson’s object mapper in a Roo generated project. You need to put those snippet into webmvc-config to replace the default objectmapper with your custom one:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
   <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
       <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
           <property name="objectMapper">
               <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
                   <property name="objectMapper">
                       <array>
                           <bean class="com.yourproject.example.CustomObjectMapper"/>
                       </array>
                   </property>
               </bean>
           </property>
       </bean>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Hope it helps. To be able to configure Jackson with a code based config you need setup WebApplicationInitializer 
You can find more info by link:http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html

Answer (score 2):

spring-boot allows jackson configuration through `spring.jackson.*` properties in .properties files.

```
spring.jackson.serialization.indent-output=true
```

We can also `@Autowire` this configured `ObjectMapper` in @Components. If global configuration is not intended then `objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()` turns on the default indentation.

Tested with spring-boot 1.5.8.RELEASE which uses jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Jenky answer, here is example how to configure Jackson's mapper for pretty print using code approach. I'm using `spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE` in this example. Simply have this class on your classpath and Spring Boot will pick it up auto-magically.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void extendMessageConverters( List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters ) {

        for ( HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters ) {

            if ( converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter ) {

                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;

                jacksonConverter.setPrettyPrint( true );

            }

        }

    }

}
```