# How to make the `@Endpoint(id = "health")` working in Spring Boot 2.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have tried the new way of customizing the health Actuator in Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5, as described here: https://spring.io/blog/2017/08/22/introducing-actuator-endpoints-in-spring-boot-2-0:

```java
@Endpoint(id = "health")
public class HealthEndpoint {
    @ReadOperation
    public Health health() {
        return new Health.Builder()
            .up()
            .withDetail("MyStatus", "is happy")
            .build();
    }
}
```

However, when I run HTTP GET to `localhost:port/application/health`, I still get the standard default health info. My code is completely ignored.

When I use the "traditional way" of customizing the health info via implementation of `HealthIndicator`, it works as expected, the health information is decorated with the given details:

```java
@Component
public class MyHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return new Health.Builder()
            .up()
            .withDetail("MyStatus 1.1", "is happy")
            .withDetail("MyStatus 1.2", "is also happy")
            .build();
    }
}
```

---

**QUESTION**: What more shall I configure and/or implement to make the `@Endpoint(id = "health")` solution working?

My intention is *not* to create a custom actuator `myhealth`, but to customize the existing `health` actuator. Based on the documentation I expect to reach the same result as by implementing HealthIndicator. Am I wrong in that assumption?

---

The Maven configuration `pom.xml` contains:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M5</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The Spring Boot configuration `application.properties` contains:

```
endpoints.health.enabled=true
endpoints.autoconfig.enabled=true
endpoints.autoconfig.web.enabled=true
```

Comment: Have you configured your `HealthEndpoint` as a bean? To do so, you'd typically declare a `@Bean` method for it or, if you're using component scanning, annotate it with `@Component`

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Well, I would expect that `@Endpoint`-annotated classes are scanned automagically in Spring Boot. However, now I tried to add also `@Component` before the `@Endpoint` and there is no difference.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: Indra Basak already answered to me in his comment below, that my failure was based on a wrong assumption. So probably you would not be able to make it working either :) I edited my question so it should be more clear. Indra: "The documentation is trying to explain the new endpoint infrastructure with the existing health endpoint as an example. A new endpoint ID has to be unique and shouldn't be same as an existing actuator endpoint."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update

- The [documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2017/08/22/introducing-actuator-endpoints-in-spring-boot-2-0) on the new Spring Actuator Endpoints is not very lucid. It's trying to explain the new endpoint infrastructure with the existing health endpoint as an example.
- A new endpoint ID has to be **unique** and shouldn't be same as an existing actuator endpoint. If one tries to the change the ID of the example shown below to `health`, one will get the following exception:

  ```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found two endpoints with the id 'health'
  ```
- The above comment about declaring the endpoint classes with `@Bean` annotation is correct.
- Customizing the `health` endpoint hasn't changed in Spring Boot 2.0. You still have to implement `HealthIndicator` to add custom values.

### Custom Actuator Endpoint

Here are the changes needed to create a custom Actuator endpoint in Spring Boot 2.0.

#### Model

The domain containing your custom information.

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class MyHealth {

    private Map<String, Object> details;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getDetails() {
        return this.details;
    }
}
```

#### My Health Endpoint

Declaring `myhealth` endpoint,

```
@Endpoint(id = "myhealth")
public class MyHealthEndpoint {

    @ReadOperation
    public MyHealth health() {
        Map<String, Object> details = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        details.put("MyStatus", "is happy");
        MyHealth health = new MyHealth();
        health.setDetails(details);

        return health;
    }
}
```

#### My Health Extension

Extension for `myhealth` endpoint,

```
@WebEndpointExtension(endpoint = MyHealthEndpoint.class)
public class MyHealthWebEndpointExtension {

    private final MyHealthEndpoint delegate;

    public MyHealthWebEndpointExtension(MyHealthEndpoint delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @ReadOperation
    public WebEndpointResponse<MyHealth> getHealth() {
        MyHealth health = delegate.health();
        return new WebEndpointResponse<>(health, 200);
    }
}
```

#### Actuator Configuration

Configuration to expose the two newly created actuator classes as beans,

```
@Configuration
public class ActuatorConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint
    public MyHealthEndpoint myHealthEndpoint() {
        return new MyHealthEndpoint();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint
    @ConditionalOnBean({MyHealthEndpoint.class})
    public MyHealthWebEndpointExtension myHealthWebEndpointExtension(
            MyHealthEndpoint delegate) {
        return new MyHealthWebEndpointExtension(delegate);
    }
}
```

#### Application Properties

Changes to `application.yml`,

```
endpoints:
  myhealth:
    enabled: true
```

Once you start your application, you should be able to access the newly actuator endpoint at `http://<host>:<port>/application/myhealth`.

You should expect a response similar to one shown below,

```
{
  "MyStatus": "is happy"
}
```

A complete working example can be found [here](https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-actuator-example).

Comment: Thanks, it - almost - works :) Somehow it duplicates the information, the output is {
"details": {
"MyStatus": "is happy"
},
"MyStatus": "is happy"
}

Answer (score -1):

Provide your own `@WebEndpoint` like

```
@Component
@WebEndpoint(id = "acmehealth")
public class AcmeHealthEndpoint {

    @ReadOperation
    public String hello() {
      return "hello health";
    }
}
```

and

1. include it
2. map the original /health to, say, /internal/health
3. map your custom endpoint to /health

via `application.properties`:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=acmehealth
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=internal/health
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.acmehealth=/health
```

This will override /health completely, not just add the information to the existing /health, as a custom `HealthIndicator` would. Question is, what you want, because `@Endpoint(id = "health")` and "My intention is not to create a custom actuator myhealth, but to customize the existing health actuator" kind of collide. But you *can* use the existing `HealthEndpoint` in your AcmeHealthEndpoint and accomplish both:

```
@Component
@WebEndpoint(id = "prettyhealth")
public class PrettyHealthEndpoint {

    private final HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    public PrettyHealthEndpoint(HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.healthEndpoint = healthEndpoint;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @ReadOperation(produces = "application/json")
    public String getHealthJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Health health = healthEndpoint.health();
        ObjectWriter writer = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        return writer.writeValueAsString(health);
    }

    @ReadOperation
    public String prettyHealth() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return "<html><body><pre>" + getHealthJson() + "</pre></body></html>";
    }
}
```